# Rhythm or Laya in Bansuri

Tags: rhythm, indian-classical, bansuri

I am struggling with the concept of Rhythm or Laya in Bansuri

Right now, understand that Laya is the speed at which notes are played one after another.

But how do I read Bansuri notes such that I understand the Laya. There are many resources on Google that discuss Laya, but I just cannot seem to comprehend it.

And one Bansuri video tutorial (at end of this post) shows the instructor playing 4-4 Tabla app in background, but I am unsure of how that helps with Laya.

Why does he need 4-4 Tabla?

So far, I am reading Bansuri notes for tunes I am very familiar with.

For instance, [Om Jai Jagdish Hare](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ChSzECkdew) first line is

`Om Jai Jagdish Hare`

I instinctively play it as

`S S SSS SNR`

Any advice for this newcomer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@brahadeesh suggested making comment into answer. So here it is

---

He doesn't “need” 4-4 time.  He's just happened to match the melody (scale or sargam) to 4-4 time (taal) . [Here](https://youtu.be/ACAtp_dg7Uc) he does it in 3-3 and [here](https://youtu.be/eG1EoDl1xTI) in rupak (7) and jhaptal (5-5)

## Note

Western and Indian timing notations are different – the denominator is always a power of 2 in western

- 3-3 : dadra : 3/4
- 4-4 : keherwa (bhajani) : 8/4
- 4-4-4-4 : teentaal : 16/4 or 16/8
- 5-5 : jhaptal : 10/4 or 10/8
- 7 : rupak : 7/8

## Friendly suggestion

Don't try to *think* of the taal; instead just play along with the YouTube. For that tuning may be necessary... 
If I were to do it I'd use

- YouTube downloader
- ffmpeg to convert video to audio
- audacity to retune.

If you need more guidance ask another question!!